# 4.5 adobe builder/flex eventhandler/skinablepopupcontainer returned data empty

Tags: apache-flex, event-listener

I am new to Flex and am having problems figuring out why this eventlistener always returns null for the event.data.  I am trying to implement a simple yes/no prompt for data removal. I have included the skinnable container code and the calling mxml. The alertDB_close handler fires I know that but the event.data is empty. thanks for any suggestions

Main mxml:

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{


// Create an instance of MyAlertPopUp.
var alertDB:AlertMsgPurge = new AlertMsgPurge();
// Add an event handler for the close event to check for 
// any returned data.
alertDB.addEventListener('close', alertDB_closeHandler);
alertDB.open(this, true);

}
private function alertDB_closeHandler(eventP:PopUpEvent):void {
// If commit is false, do data is returned.

rd.text = eventP.data as String;
//return;

                /
}
```

AlertMsgPurge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>

    <![CDATA[
        // //
    public function onClick(commit:Boolean):void {
    close(true);                           
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TitleWindow title="" x="75" y="300">

    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8"    paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
        <s:Label text="Warning!! all data will be deleted"/>
        <s:Button label="Yes" click="close(true);"/>
        <s:Button label="No" click="close(false);"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: Why you cant try this using custom events ?

Answer (score 0):

With that function modified:

```
private function alertDB_closeHandler(eventP:PopUpEvent):void {
        trace("eventdata:"+eventP.commit);
}
```

You can see if the user clicked "yes" or "no" then you can do your processing.
Is it what your looking for?